# Express alias query strings as params

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I am making a project with node, express, and jade. I want to access content through:

```
/Page/foo/bar
```

and

```
/Page?Foo=foo&Bar=bar
```

I want the top to be an alias for the bottom.

This is the solution I have now:

server.js

```
// some stuff
app.get('/Page/:Foo/:Bar',function(req,res){
    res.render('Page.jade', {Foo: req.params.Foo, Bar: req.params.Bar});
});
app.get('/Page',function(req,res){
    res.render('Page.jade', {Foo: req.query.Foo, Bar: req.query.Bar});
});
// more stuff
```

Page.jade

```
doctype html
html
    head
        script var foo = "!{Foo}"; bar = "!{Bar}";
        script(src="/Page.js")
// stuff
```

Page.js

```
// stuff with foo and bar, such as:
console.log(foo);
console.log(bar);
```

The thing I don't like about this solution is that it forces me to handle the params and query separately with express (which is almost duplicate code, but not quite close enough to reduce it), pass it to jade, which stores it in a variable for the sole purpose of having a linked javascript file use those variables.

Normally just using query strings I would only have to touch it in Page.js. Is there a way to set up express to effectively interpret the first URL as a query string, like the second URL, so the jade file doesn't have to touch the variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **Option 1:** If you just want to reduce code redundancy, maybe you could save your controllers in an external file, so you will end up with something like this:

  `controllers/fooBarController.js`:

  ```
  exports.fooBarQueryOrParams = function(req, res) {
      res.render('Page.jade', {
          Foo: req.params.Foo || req.query.Foo,
          Bar: req.params.Bar || req.query.Bar
      });
  }
  ```

  You could also add a default value with another `||` operator if `undefined` is not valid four you.

  `server.js`:

  ```
  var fooBarController = require('controllers/fooBarController');

  app.get('/Page/:Foo/:Bar',    fooBarController.fooBarQueryOrParams);
  app.get('/Page',              fooBarController.fooBarQueryOrParams);
  ```
- **Option 2:** Same thing, but using [`res.locals`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.locals), so now there's no need to pass any object to `Page.js`, **all your views** will see [`res.locals`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.locals) properties just by its names, in this case `Foo` and `Bar` (not `res.locals.Foo` and `res.locals.Bar`).

  `controllers/fooBarController.js`:

  ```
  exports.fooBarQueryOrParams = function(req, res) {
      res.locals.Foo = req.params.Foo || req.query.Foo;
      res.locals.Bar = req.params.Bar || req.query.Bar;
      res.render('Page.jade');
  }
  ```

  `server.js`:

  ```
  var fooBarController = require('controllers/fooBarController');

  app.get('/Page/:Foo/:Bar',    fooBarController.fooBarQueryOrParams);
  app.get('/Page',              fooBarController.fooBarQueryOrParams);
  ```
- **Option 3:** Always expose everything thought [`res.locals`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.locals):

  `controllers/fooBarController.js`:

  ```
  exports.fooBarQueryOrParams = function(req, res) {
      res.render('Page.jade');
  }
  ```

  `server.js`:

  ```
  var fooBarController = require('controllers/fooBarController');

  app.use(function(req, res, next) {
      for (var key in req.params) res.locals[key] = req.params[key];
      for (var key in req.query)  res.locals[key] = req.query[key];
      next();
  });

  app.get('/Page/:Foo/:Bar',    fooBarController.fooBarQueryOrParams);
  app.get('/Page',              fooBarController.fooBarQueryOrParams);
  ```

I would go for the first option as I suppose you don't really need to use `Foo` and `Bar` in all your views, so there's no point in using `res.locals` to expose them to all your views instead of just to the ones that really need them.

Answer (score 0):

You could just set the object properties yourself and continue to the next route etc

```
app.use('/Page/:Foo/:Bar',function(req, res, next){

    for (var key in req.params) {
        req.query[key] = req.params[key];
    }

    next();

});
```

Comment: This only lets express see the query values, not the Page.js file, unless I'm missing something.